# how to send and recv c struct between udp server(in c) and udp client(python)?

Tags: python, c, network-programming, udp, client-server

I have this structure

```
struct Data
{
      int id;
      int msglen;
      char msg[100];
}
```

and I need to pass this struct between udp server and udp client.udp client is python based.

Comment: And what are you planning to do with that struct in the client side?

Comment: just analysing the msg at both sides and send the response accordingly

Comment: And how are you planning to analyze the C struct in the python code?

Comment: Your question is too broad. There are a lot of steps and code to get from that struct to both a server and a client. So what exact aspect are you asking about? It would be best if you showed what code you have done so far or ask a more specific question.

Comment: @MohithReddy analysing c struct is my main doubt i.e how to pack the struct at python and receive at c.Then unpacking the struct received from c server.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to encode the struct data into a single binary buffer

```c
#include <endian.h>
...
struct Data d { ... };

uint32_t be_id = htobe32(d.id);
uint32_t be_len = htobe32(d.msglen);

size_t pos = 0;
uint8_t buf[sizeof(struct Data)];

memcpy(buf, (const void *)&be_id, sizeof(be_id));
pos += sizeof(be_id);

memcpy(buf + pos, (const void *)&be_len, sizeof(be_len));
pos += sizeof(be_len);

memcpy(buf + pos, (const void *)d.msg, sizeof(d.msg));
```

Then send the buffer, and parse it from the other side.

Comment: Why not just send the struct?  Why copy it?

Comment: @MartinJames Issues with structure padding, I suppose...

Comment: @MartinJames because of padding and endianness differences among different architectures